# WebClient.DownloadFile() within Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, webclient, parallel-processing

This code works fine :

```
Parallel.ForEach(photos, item =>
            {
                WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
                webClient.DownloadFile(item.src_big, "C:\\pic" + item.ID + ".jpg");
            });
```

While this code throws "An exception occurred during a WebClient request." :

```
foreach (Photo p in photos)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
                    webClient.DownloadFile(p.src_big, "C:\\pic" + p.ID + ".jpg");
                });
        }
```

I got two questions :

1) In the first code I am using multiple WebClient objects for downloading. Same thing goes for the second code, so why do I get the exception ?

2) I am trying those two versions to determine what is the fastest way to download photos, in my case from facebook. I would like to know if there is another method that is faster, maybe WebRequest.Create() ?

Comment: Asnwer to 2 is that i am using same procedure and it works fine for me parallel.foreach has reduced time much

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are [closing over the loop variable](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx) in the second case - try this:

```
foreach (Photo p in photos)
        {
            Photo photo = p;
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
                    webClient.DownloadFile(photo.src_big, "C:\\pic" + photo.ID + ".jpg");
                });
        }
```

Also `Parallel.ForEach()` is synchronous - after it has executed, all files have been downloaded. The tasks on the other hand could still be ongoing so you will have to wait for them to complete, probably something like this would be more appropriate for the second case:

```
var tasks = photos.Select(  p => Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            using(WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
            webClient.DownloadFile(p.src_big, string.Format(@"C:\pic{0}.jpg",p.ID));
        })).ToArray();
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

As you can see `Parallel.ForEach()` in this case is much preferred since the syntax is very terse, under the hood they both use the Thread Pool, so choose the simplest option you can get away with, especially since you don't need the added complexity.

Also I don't think you would be getting your data faster using a `WebRequest` - most of the delay will be caused by the network / internet and not which of the two you choose - that being the case I'd opt for the simpler code, which is definitely using the `WebClient`.

To sum it up: I'd go for `Parallel.ForEach()` with a `WebClient`, option **1**.

Comment: cool, Worked! and what about my second question, do you have any insights ?

Comment: Ok, but what about webclient.DownloadData() ? if it's faster, maybe I can use it instead, and do the convertion to jpg in another thread ?

Comment: I think you are over-thinking this one - but I encourage you to do some performance testing using both approaches - I don't think either will be significantly faster than the other - so make it as simple as you can get away with.

Comment: I checked the download rate with the Network Meter gadget and indeed my download rate is at 700kb which is my max. So solution 1 is the fast as it can get.

Answer (score 0):

Asnwer to 2 is that i am using same procedure and it works fine for me parallel.foreach has reduced time much

When i analysed the statics then i observed that if i have large number of pictures to fetch then parallel.foreach launches so many threads that it is almost reaches the cpapcity of my broadband like i have max regular download speed of 100kb/sec so downloading pics reached 100kb this means that it could not get any better than this because it is the internet that matters the most

Comment: Good point ! I will check the download rate. by the way, how do you check it ? (-: ( I mean what is the most accurate way )

Comment: simple is that My LAN  is connected at 100 Mbps and when i run this process i can see its consumption via taskmanager and it comes to be 1% which means 1Mbps